# USB limits the speed of two network cards while doesn't limit the speed of two flash driver,why?

Tags: wireless-networking

I used two network card to transfer data, it turned out that when one was working at a speed of about 2MB/s,the other one had little speed. They just could not work at the same time at high speed like 2MB/s when only one card worked at a time. but when I tested the speed by using two flash drivers ((pen drives?) don't know how to say it in English correctly). There was no such limitation for flash drivers.I mean that two flash drivers could work at the same time at hight speed. who can help me explain this please?

PS.it is wireless network card that I used and each one connected to a different AP that worked in different channels.

Comment: Welcome to Superuser, what OS are you using?

Comment: There's a few possibilities I can think of. Radio channel congestion is one (remember that wireless channels overlap in the frequency domain), and then there's the possibility that the USB ports you are using have different characteristics, or that for some reason the network cards can't negotiate more than a ~20 Mbit/s link (which would give you around 2 MB/s throughput). We need more information to be able to tell you what might be wrong, and as @50-3 said a good start would be what OS you are using (so we can tell you how to find the information we need).

Comment: How much distance is there between your two network adapter ?

Comment: very near...because the two USB ports that i used is one beside another@BatchyX

Comment: i used Ubuntu,linux kernel 3.5...and need more information please ask...@50-3 @Michael Kjörling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> > How much distance is there between your two network adapter ?
>
> very near... because the two USB ports that i used is one beside another

Well, here's your problem.

If the antennas are too close, the two cards will interact badly, since one of them will saturate the signal level as soon as it transmits, even if they are on different channels.  This can leads to all kind of problems.

These sort of problems can even caused by insufficiently-shielded radio chips being close together.

The further your network cards are from each other, the better.  Plug a stupid USB cable if needed.